# How to understand "{ fun: function.bind(this) }"?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 2;
var c = {
    a: 3,
    say: function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }.bind(this);
};
c.say();
// Ouput: 2
```

The output is 2, and I don't know why. Why *this* point to *global*?

Comment: Default value of `this` is window

Comment: Are you using Node.js?

Comment: I think you  might confuse the global var a with module's property a. 
Try var Geta = retrievea.bind(c); 
Geta() after and remove the bind(this);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this statement is executed in global scope:

```
var a = 2;
```

it's equal to `window.a = 2`.

In your code the first thing that happens is the `.bind(this)` method is executed. Since you're in a global scope, `this` here points to `window`. So, the `say` function is bound to the `window` and `this.a` inside this function sort of becomes `window.a` and accordingly this `console.log(this.a)` becomes `console.log(window.a)`.

In order to understand the behavior, you have to first understand what `bind` does. Check this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). Check this, for example:

```
var a = 2;
var c = {
    a: 3,
    say: function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }.bind({a: 7});
};
c.say(); // outputs 7
```

Comment: Is the `.bind(this)` method executed when `c` was defined? Or it is executed when I executed `c.say()`?

Comment: @Maxmengt, it was executed before the `c` was defined and initialized, because the value for `say` is required to initialize `c`.

Comment: @Maxmengt, is there anything else unclear? If you found my answer helpful, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

As you're in an anonymous function you're not calling out of `c`. Use `c.a` instead.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I'm swiss (native swiss-german speaker) and try to write as good english as possible. Sometimes I fail, but im always thankful for people like you! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Default value for `this` is `window`. Also since your code is not wrapped in a function, `var a` becomes a part of `window`

Try wrapping it inside an IIFE

```js
(function() {
  var a = 2;
  var c = {
    a: 3,
    say: function() {
      console.log(this.a);
    }.bind(this)
  };
  c.say();
})()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)